# Tu app tiene un APK con el código de versión 1 que solicita los siguientes permisos: android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console, android-permissions, android-manifest

estoy usando expo para crear una aplicación móvil con react-native. No tengo problemas en generar la apk y probarla en un dispositivo Android simulado. La cosa es que cuando subo la apk a la consola de google play me sale el siguiente error:

Tu app tiene un APK con el código de versión 1 que solicita los siguientes permisos: android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.READ_CONTACTS. Las apps que usan estos permisos en un APK deben tener configurada una política de privacidad.

Sin embargo en ninguna parte de mi app uso los permisos ni nada. Como puedo solucionar esto? como puedo eliminar los permisos?

edit: No se donde está el archivo manifest, o donde lo genera expo, ya que hay muchos archivos androidManifest.xml y no se cual de ellos editar.

Comment: Quita esos permisos desde el manifiest.xml

Comment: mejir busca como agregarle la politica de seguridad...

Comment: @Riven donde está el archivo manifest generado por expo? no puedo encontrarlo

Answer (score 1):

Expo agrega algunos permisos por default en tu aplicación, pero si no los necesitas puedes eliminarlos.

Solo tienes que modificar el apartado "android.permissions" de tu archivo app.json para agregar solo los permisos que necesitas.

Por ejemplo, si solo necesitas los permisos de la cámara quedaría algo así

```
    "android": {
      "package": "gl.js.app",
      "permissions": [ "CAMERA"],
      "versionCode": 36
    }
```

Si quieres ver el listado completo de permisos que puedes poner los encuentra aquí
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions

Espero que te sea de ayuda